# SARIMA model selection for my data

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, seasonality, differencing

I am new to time series analysis.
I need to determine whether my series is seasonal or not, and if it requires differencing for building an ARIMA model if it is possible? The time series data is monthly.
Thank you!
[image]